# Adding two Table Views to the main View in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I placed two Table View's onto my main.storyboard. I then created two new .swift class files for them: VideoTableViewController and LinkTableViewController. How do I link the two? It looks like I may have done this wrong because I read I need to have the delegate linked to the View that the Table View is on. I want it linked to the controller I created for the Table View. 
What I am trying to do is have two lists side by side, one with video links and another with web links. I already have the data in arrays. I just need to get that data into the cells of the proper table view.

I noticed I can drop a Table View Controller onto the storyboard, but i don't think that
's what I want since it's an entirely different view. I would like for these to be on the same view.

VideoTableViewController:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class VideoTableViewController: UITableViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var videoTable = UITableView()

var videos: [Video] = []

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!  {

    //disable header
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-30, 0, -20, 0);

    var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Component") as UITableViewCell

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Component")
    }

    //cell.textLabel.text = "Baking Soda"
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = "1/2 cup"

    return cell
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.videos.count
}

func setVideos(videos:[Video]) {
    self.videos = videos
}
}
```

The main ViewController:

This fills the arrays of objects then passes the array to the proper table controller.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//arrays to hold objects
var videos  :[Video] = []
var links   :[Link] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.fillArrays()

    //instantiate TableViewController
    let videoTable = VideoTableViewController()
    let linkTable = LinkTableViewController()
    videoTable.setVideos(videos)
    linkTable.setLinks(links)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func fillArrays() {
    let file = File()
    let path = "/Users/me/file.rtf"

    if (file.exists(path)) {                                        //if file exists
        let read :String? = file.read(path)                         //read the file
        let content :String = read!                                 //get file content
        let lines = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")       //explode content on line breaks

        var lineItem :[String]                                      //to hold each item of line explode
        for line in lines {                                         //loop through lines
            lineItem = line.componentsSeparatedByString(",")        //explode line on commas

            //instantiate an object for the line, initialize it, and append the object to its array
            switch lineItem[0] {
            case "L":
                self.links += Link(image: lineItem[0], path: lineItem[1])
            case "V":
                var duration :Int = 100
                self.videos += Video(image: lineItem[1], path: lineItem[2], title: lineItem[3], duration: duration)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

So, am I going about this wrong? Apparently it is an odd thing I am doing since I can't find much straight forward info on it Googling.

Comment: Usually you want to opt for a MVC style application where a view controller handles giving the data for its views: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html. That being said if you are trying to connect the table views to a specific class you can change their class in interface builder.

Comment: are you saying you want only one view controller to manage 2 tableviews?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want 2 tableviews in the same view controller do the following:

1. Create a UIViewController that is a delegate to

   ```
   UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
   ```
2. Add 2 uitableviews to this view controller in the storyboard
3. Add 2 IBOutlets for the UITableViews in your ViewController.h file like this:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
   @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView2;
   ```
4. Connect the IBOutlets to these.
5. Add the delegate functions for the tableview in the .m file somethng like this:

   ```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
       // Return the number of rows in the section.
       if(tableView == self.tableView1){
           return whatever1;
       }

       if(tableView == self.tableView2){
           return whatever2;
       }
    }
   ```

Comment: I guess I am just not following. If I create a UIViewController then am I not going to have to drag the controller from that box in the right-hand bottom corner onto the storyboard? I could've done that with the table views but I couldn't put that Table View Controller onto the default View Controller. I would be open to have some sort of tabbing thing on the left side of the screen that would pop out the table view when selected. However, I still don't know how one would do such a thing since I wouldn't want the table view using the entire screen's real estate. Regardless, thanks a lot!

Comment: I was proposing that you drag out a ViewController, and then put 2 Tableviews in it. You can access them both from the left tab. And they dont have to be full screen. Sorry i am not able to understand what the issue is.

Comment: @hackerinheels, bro Could you help me my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757311/2-table-view-in-one-view-controller-with-swift-3 ?

Answer (score 0):

@hackerinheels' proposed solution worked for me in a bit of a different setting: using a UITableView like a radio button group in a View Controller. It didn't work initially because I missed this step in hooking up the delegate and data source in viewDidLoad() of the View Controller:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

After this step is added, it started working nicely.

Even though this might be a no-brainer for experienced folks, but for a layman like me, spelling it out can be very helpful.

As for the solution for 2 TableViews in one View Controller, @hackerinheels' proposed 5 steps + the above change in viewDidLoad(), would work nicely!