# Int and int is not Convertible To Int - (Return 2 arrays, UITableView)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

i created two arrays for a UITableView. How do i return 2 values? Im getting this error saying that "(Int/Int) is not convertible to 'Int'". So as you can see i return 2 arrays which are strings. The app is basically, a uiTableView that displays the arrays. I began with One array and it worked then i created a second array but im getting a error. The second array is going to be a subtitle. The first array is a title of the cell.

Code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (self.footballNews.count, self.footballSub.count) //returns the array that we made
}
```

Comment: You do realise a tuple is not an Int?

Comment: If what you want is to return the sum of the 2 arrays ocount then just add them together: return self.footballNews.count + self.footballSub.count

Comment: Do you want to display two table views? Then have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25021646/1187415.

Comment: It depends on what you have or try to do: two sections in one view, two views with one section each or just one section in one view!? Or do you still have only one actual section and two data points for each entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say

> The second array is going to be a subtitle. The first array is a title of the cell.

I assume that for each cell you have exactly one title and exactly one subtitle!

Therefore it does not matter what value you return as long as you just return one. Currently you return a tuple of two Int. That does conflict with the expected return type of the function signature. You should just keep your old code with only one array, which was probably something like

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return self.footballNews.count
}
```

Comment: So do you know how i add a subtitle. Im new ish to Swift

Comment: in what way do you want to "add" a subtitle? In general the subtitle is just another part of the cell you already display: `detailTextLabel` might be suitable for your need in the way that you can set the `textLabel` to the news headline and the detail to its subtitle.