# Swift: TableView in ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `ViewController` in the `MainstoryBoard`.  I added the `TableView` 
to it.

**MainStoryBoard:**

[image]

In addition I have an array outside of the `ViewController` class and I want the objects inside the array to be shown in the `TableView`.

I can't figure out how to do it. I connected the delegate between the `TableView` and the `ViewController`.

Comment: refer this link http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/
https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya Great, It works! "weheartswift" has the answer

Comment: Welcome any time @Eliko you every this is fine on google.

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya do you know what I need to do if I want to put 2 table views in 1 view controller?

Comment: first you set every tableView datasource and delegate then you set tableView tag. for ex table1 tag is 101 and second table tag  is 102. Then u check every tableView delegate method like this way.
if(table1.tag==101){ //table1 cell coding}else { //second table cell code}

Comment: refer this link for more idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215475/two-tables-on-one-view-in-swift

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019136/adding-two-table-views-to-the-main-view-in-xcode

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya PERFECT! thank you! and please write it as answer so I can make it the correct answer

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You add a new table view instance variable below the class declaration.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

To conform to the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocol just add them separated by commas after `UIViewController` in the class declaration

After that we need to implement the `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`, `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` and `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` methods in the `ViewController` class and leave them empty for now

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    ...

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0 // your number of cells here
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // your cell coding 
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // cell selected code here
    }
}
```

As mentioned by @ErikP in the comments, you also need to
set

`self.tableView.delegate = self`

`self.tableView.dataSource = self`

in the `viewDidLoad` method.

(or in Storyboard works well too).

Comment: I thought this was going to work but when I get to my do_table_refresh function and call: `self.tableView.reloadData()` it fails with `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: You will need to set `self.tableView.delgate = self` and `self.tableView.dataSource = self` in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
Write weak to except retain cycle

Comment: In your storyboard, don't forget to Drag from the table view to the yellow circle on top of the view controller. Let go and choose "dataSource". Do this again but choose delegate instead.

Comment: It's also useful to add         
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;

Answer (score 1):

i might be late and you may have fixed this by now.
The error you are getting is due to your variable or constant returning a nil value. to test this you can assign a value to it (hard code it) and check the full code if it is working and then change it to your array, unfortunately i do stuff programmatically and not very familiar with the storyboard.

if you share your code we will be assist you if this is not yet sorted.