# UIPickerView placement on top of view

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am trying to place a UIPickerView on top of my TableView when a button is clicked. I tried using the storyboard, but it moves the rows of the table down. What I want is the picker to appear as a popover when the button is clicked, then disappear when an option is selected.

Here is the code I am using to get the picker to display:

```
let picker = UIPickerView()

let container = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(container)

picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
picker.dataSource = self
picker.delegate = self
view.addSubview(picker)
picker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
picker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
picker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor).isActive = true
picker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
picker.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.required, for: .horizontal)
```

However, the picker shows up like this:

[image]

I don't understand why the picker view is not stretched until the end because I am setting the `trailingAnchor` as the parent view's `trailingAnchor`.

Comment: Why don't you give constraint directly to view.  rather than UILayoutGuide ? . If you are using UILayoutGuide then it will work without any constraints (I don't have idea about UILayoutGuide)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the best way to do it, in the Interface Builder itself. I had to change the TableViewController to a ViewController and put the TableView inside of it (setting the ViewController as a TableViewDelegate and TableViewDataSource). This allowed me to place the PickerView on the IB, as a layered view on top of my table cells. Then I could hide and show it as I pleased by creating an IBOutlet for it and setting the `.isHidden` property appropriately.

More info here: [Swift: TableView in ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673607/swift-tableview-in-viewcontroller)

Answer (score 2):

Have you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of your picker view to `false`? It ignores constraints unless you do that

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: It's not in the example code, though. I asked in case it is being set somewhere else. If it is not, that is the reason the constraints do nothing. Can't see why this should be a comment, since it specifies exactly why example code doesn't work, though it may be in a form of a question.

Answer (score 0):

If *trailing anchor* is not working, then try setting *left, top and right* to 0 and *provide a height as well* (if you don't wish to cover the complete tableView) .

> Also, add your pickerView on top of your tableView for these
>   constraints to be applied

[image: Do it like this]

If you wish to do it programatically, you can provide the constraints while you're creating the `UIPickerView` object

```
let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
```

Comment: How do I add the picker view on top of the table view? As opposed to pushing down the table rows?

Comment: `tableView.addSubView(pickerView)`

Comment: I meant in the IB.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of the layout guide, you can directly use your table view as of your relative view.**

**Coding Example:**

```
    func addPickerView() {
        let picker = UIPickerView()

//        let container = UILayoutGuide()
//        view.addLayoutGuide(container)

        picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        picker.dataSource = self
        picker.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(picker)
        picker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        picker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        picker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        picker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        picker.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.required, for: .horizontal)

    }
```

**Above code produces the following output which is stretched to its parent view.**

[image]

Comment: I have kept normal View as relative to give constraint to picker view. It's showing picker view is stretching to its parent leading and trailing.

Answer (score 0):

Set constraints equal to parent view then show perfect.

```
let topBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height +
        (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
let picker = UIPickerView()
picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let container = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(container)

picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
picker.dataSource = self
picker.delegate = self
view.addSubview(picker)
picker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
picker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
picker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: topBarHeight).isActive = true
picker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
picker.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.required, for: .horizontal)
```