# 2 Table View in One View Controller with Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3, xcode8, tablecell

I have 2 table views in one  View Controller.  I declare these two tables.

```
@IBOutlet weak var packTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var mediapackTableView: UITableView!
```

I declare this code in ViewDidLoad.

```
    mediapackTableView.delegate = self
    mediapackTableView.dataSource = self
    mediapackTableView.register(MediaPackTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mediaPackCell")

    packTableView.delegate = self
    packTableView.dataSource = self
```

and I also add these following codes.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(packSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex != 2)
    {

        debugPrint("This is NOOOOOOOO")
        let cell: TableViewCell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "packCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1

        cell.lblId.isHidden = true
         SwiftLoading().hideLoading()
         returnValues = cell
         return returnValues


    } //segemented control check

    else if packSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {

        debugPrint("This is YESSSSSSSSSSSS")
        packTableView.isHidden = true
        mediapackTableView.isHidden = false
        self.lblPackDescription.text = NSLocalizedString("Media Packs", comment: "")


        let cell: TableViewCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mediaPackCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell2
        cell.textLabel?.text = "SOFTWARE"


            debugPrint("HELLO")
          return returnValues


    } 


    return returnValues
}
```

I got error when I click on Third Segmented Control. 
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier mediaPackCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'** 
My reference video is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYJRQyAtQYg

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: You have to insert one more else condition in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: @Swift_Guru, where bro? if mediapackTableView.isHidden == false {} , this one?

Comment: check your code where else part is missing, put there else condition

Comment: @Swift_Guru, bro Could you please look at my code again? I modify the code. I still got the problem.  :(

Comment: again there is no else condition after else if , please put it first.

Comment: btw what are you going to do, what is the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's an issue with the cell identified of mediaPackCell. While it could be a few things related to it - did you set it on the UI?